# One to one relation assign created object in ef code first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entity like these

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Company RegisteredCompany { get; set; }

..
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to create new user with created company

```
using (var ctx = new AppContext())
{
    var company = ctx.Companies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == model.CompanyId);

    ...
        var user = new User
                       {
                           UserName = model.Msisdn, 
                           RegisteredCompany = company,
                           ...
                       };

        var result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Helper.GetUniqueKey(30));
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ...
        }

    ...

}
```

i get error like this

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

if i detach object in context like this

```
var company = ctx.Companies.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == model.CompanyId);
```

of course its see that new object and create new company in database. How can i assign exist company to new user ?

Comment: If you want to assign existing entity as a navigation to a new user, you either have to save the user where you fetch the company, or you have to make use of foreign key associations and just say `User.CompanyID = ...`

Comment: if i dont understand wrong , you prefer to create entity like that         `public int RegisteredCompanyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RegisteredCompanyId")]
        public virtual Company RegisteredCompany { get; set; }`

Comment: I don't prefer it, but if you have to work with navigation properties cross-context it's pretty much the only way. If you can change the `UserManager.CreateAsync` method, you can also pass your current context to it and it should work.

Comment: thanks for help.i'm working on it